# Select list on iphone looks strange

Tags: css, mobile

I am building a mobile stylesheet for a site and have hit a snag with the select lists on two pages.

here is a link:  http://www.mniac.com/roche/multiple-positions.php

You will notice it looks fine in the desktop browser but if test on the iphone or the ios simulator the select list in any of the accordions looks kinda blank (stripped of standard styling)...  Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you apply any CSS for select menu in mobile stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these both properties from the stylesheet and then try

background-image:
background-color:

Comment: Yea these styles have just become a bit of a mess.. that was it.